# Best way to deserialize GlobalID objects for tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I would like to test that when a form is submitted, a specific job is queued, with the appropriate arguments. For this, I need to inspect the arguments passed to the job, which includes `ActiveRecord` models serialized with Global ID.

I want to do this with the fewest method invocations. Right now, I'm using this:

`GlobalID::Locator.locate(enqueued_jobs[0][:args][0]['_aj_globalid'])`

where `enqueued_jobs` is defined by `ActiveJob::TestHelper`.

Can I do it more elegantly, potentially by using some gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently looking for the same thing, and I came across the [rspec-activejob](https://github.com/gocardless/rspec-activejob) gem, which fit my needs. It allows you to write an expectation such as:

```
expect(MyAwesomeJob).to have_been_enqueued.with(global_id(user))
```